# Ionic build --release android - Throwing errors about iOS

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build

I have come back to make some updates on an Ionic 1 project today that was last built around a year ago.

I have made the changes and ran:

```
ionic build --release android
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Error: The provided path "/Users/hinge/Desktop/apps/my-app- name/platforms/ios" is not a Cordova iOS project.
```

I don't even have iOS as a platform installed... any ideas why it wont just build the android app.

Thanks.